# How can I make qtcreator change the Project view when I open a new cpp file

Tags: ide, editor, qt-creator

There is this feature that `IDEA IntelliJ` has: when a new file is opened the `Project` tree (view) automatically jump to the file opened (handy when you follow a function defined in some other file).

I'd like to know if `qtcreator` provide this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprised how hard it is to find the answer, since the button isn't hugely obvious.

The button you want is at the top of the Project pane, between "filter" and "split".  Tooltip says "synchronize with editor".